# Compose layout vertical alignment: SpaceBetween having no impact

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to push the `Upcoming` text to the bottom, while the `7 pax` text remains at the top. I used `verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween` for that column, but it is having no effect since the column is not taking the full height. If I use `fillMaxHeight` for the column to force it to take the full height, the whole row takes the full screen height, which is not expected. How can I fix this?

```
@Composable
fun SoFixClientTourCard() {
    Column {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.White)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {

            // calendar
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 4.dp)
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colors.error)
                    .shadow(1.dp)
                    .padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
            ) {
                Text("02", fontSize = 14.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = Color.White)
                Text("OCT", fontSize = 12.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = Color.White)
            }

            // tour & package name
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                    .weight(1f)
            ) {
                Text("Tanguar Haor Tour", style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                Text(
                    "Couple Non-AC + Single Non-AC + Family Non-AC + Couple AC",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                    lineHeight = 20.sp,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp)
                )
            }

            // FIXME: Align status to the bottom, pax to the top
            // pax & status
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            ) {
                Text("7 pax", fontSize = XS)
                val status = "Upcoming"
                Text(
                    status,
                    fontSize = XXXS,
                    color = Color.White,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 4.dp) // top margin
                        .background(
                            when (status.lowercase()) {
                                "upcoming" -> MaterialTheme.colors.primary
                                "cancelled" -> MaterialTheme.colors.error
                                else -> Color.DarkGray
                            }
                        )
                        .padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply an [intrinsic measurements](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements) to its parent container, in your case the `Row`.
Add the [**`height(IntrinsicSize.Min)`**](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/IntrinsicSize?hl=id#Min) modifier to your `Row` and the `fillMaxHeight()` modifier to the 3rd `Column`.
Something like:

```
Column {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.White)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp)
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
    ) {

        //....
       
        // pax & status
        Column(
            modifier= Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        ) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Gab just for my info pliz comment what does `height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` do to the `row`

Comment: @Tonnie The `Row` composable's `minIntrinsicHeight` will be the maximum `minIntrinsicHeight` of its children. The 3rd `Column` element's `minIntrinsicHeight` is `0` as it doesn't occupy space if no constraints are given; the 1st and 2nd `Column` `minIntrinsicHeight` will be that of the content given a specific width. Therefore, the `Row` element's height constraint will be the max `minIntrinsicHeight` of the 1st and 2nd `Column`. The 3rd `Column` will then expand its height to the height constraint given by the `Row`.